# Set theory, operation with products, union and intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I need to show the following using logical connectives:

$B\setminus (B \setminus A)=A \cap B $

$(A \setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)=(A \cup B)\setminus(A \cap B)$

$(A\times B\setminus C )=(A\times C)\setminus(B \times C)$

My attempt at the first one was futile, as I ran into the following:

$x \in B\setminus (B \setminus A)\iff(x\in B \land (\neg (x \in B \land (\neg(x \in A)))))\iff(x\in B \land  (\neg x \in B \lor x \in A))$

Comment: You are nearly done, notice that your left conjunct contradicts the left disjunct, so you know the left conjunct and the right disjunct. Formally distribute the $\land$ over the $\lor$ and you can simplify further.

Comment: I'm not used to the word conjunct and disjunct. The problem I see is that x can't be both in B and not in B. So how can I make sense of it? and what about the other ones?

Comment: What you have is something of the form $P\wedge (\lnot P\vee Q)$. Since $P$ must be true, and $\lnot P\vee Q$ must be true. But $\lnot P$ is false. Therefore, for $\lnot P\vee Q$ to be true, $Q$ must be true.

Comment: oh, so contradictions are always wrong, so we just look past it? Edit: why must P be true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least for first statement, use distributive law after De Morgan's:

$$\begin{align}
x\in B\setminus(B\setminus A)&\iff x\in B\wedge \neg(x\in B\setminus A)\\
&\iff x\in B \wedge\neg(x\in B\wedge\neg x\in A)\\
&\iff x\in B\wedge(\neg x\in B\vee x\in A)\\
&\iff \overbrace{(x\in B\wedge \neg x\in B)}^\text{contradiction}\vee(x\in B\wedge x\in A)\\
&\iff x\in B\wedge x\in A\\
&\iff x\in A\cap B
\end{align}$$